# Has Vegito ever used the instant transmission in canon Dragon Ball?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball-movies

The Dragon Ball wikia lists instant tranmission as one of Vegito's abilities. [Vegito](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Vegito) . Has Vegito ever used the instant transmission in canon Dragon Ball?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [wiki](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Instant_Transmission#Usage) he used it in Dragon Ball Super.

> Vegito Blue uses Instant Transmission against Fused Zamasu to use Savage Strike against him.

[image: Vegito - Instant Transmission]